# Is there a way to return the id of a row that was just created in MySQL with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

When I create a new entry in my MySQL database, I'd like the query to return the id of the  table that was just created. If it cannot do this, is there another way to find out the this id? The reason I want to do this is so I can link a new row to the row that spawned it (and there's no guarantee that they're consecutive)

Comment: Take a look yourself in the PHP manual: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You mean last autoincrement id?

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('mydb');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

You want [`mysql_insert_id()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the ID of the record you have just inserted into a table, if so you are looking for [mysql_insert_id](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php).

Answer (score 2):

have a look at https://www.php.net/mysql_insert_id

Answer (score 1):

Use the mysql_insert_id function... http://php.net/mysql_insert_id

Excuse the underscores converting the 'insert' into italics... follow the link and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have LAST_INSERT_ID() in My SQL (@@IDENTITY in ms sql) and mysql_insert_id in php.

Personally though, I try to avoid auto increments / identity columns and generate my id's in other ways. Amongst other reasons, because they make inserts into multiple tables harder.

/B