# how to get data after sql inerst command in php

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to return the id of a row that was just created in MySQL with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669942/is-there-a-way-to-return-the-id-of-a-row-that-was-just-created-in-mysql-with-php)

hi, i have an inset command such as

```
insert (name) values($name);
```

where i have id column as outoincrement how can i get the id of the inserted record after inserting directly

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669942/is-there-a-way-to-return-the-id-of-a-row-that-was-just-created-in-mysql-with-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with `mysql_*` function, you'll have to use [**`mysql_insert_id()`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) *(quoting)* :

> Retrieves the ID generated for an
>   `AUTO_INCREMENT` column by the
>   previous query (usually `INSERT`).

With mysqli, you'll use [**`mysqli::insert_id()`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).

And, with PDO, you'll call [**`PDO::lastInsertId()`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("Your query here");
$last_id = mysql_insert_id();
```